# ZeroFill DB2 Decimal

Tags: database, db2

I have a problem using DB2. I have a decimal field with precision 2. Yet, was necessary up the precision for 4. I would like to complete to zero the difference between the precision. Example 1.20 to 1.2000

I know that in mysql has the zerofill. Is there something like in DB2 ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DECIMAL(3,2)`, simply `CAST` to  `DECIMAL(5,4)`

You don't need to add the zeros.  The DB will do it for you if you change the scale & precision.